# Delete Files from subfolders where security cam clips are stored

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've searched and have seen similar scripts but I am not knowledgeable enough to figure out how to write it specifically for what I want.

I have security cam footage uploaded from onsite to my Google Drive to have a cloud backup. I would like to delete clips older than 30 days from a specific parent folder only (files are contained inside subfolders of the parent). The issue is this parent folder has subfolders for each camera's clips.

For instance the files are uploaded to a folder structure like below:

Backups
--Camera 1
--Camera 2
--Camera 3
and so on.

I only want to delete clips in each folder that are older than 30 days, I don't want to delete the subfolders because it may have other clips that are not yet older than 30 days.

Can someone help me with a script that will acheive this?

I have seen various scripts that either delete all files,or delete files in a parent folder but haven't seen a script that will only delete files in a subfolder which is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What are the exact file names?  Are they created programatically?i.e. do they have a pattern to them? Do they have a constant extension that's unique?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function findNDel(folder) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if (file.getName().match(/Camera \d+/g) ) {
      Drive.Files.remove(file.getId());
    }
  }
  const subfolders = folder.getFolders()
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    let subfolder = subfolders.next();
    findNDel(subfolder);
  }
}
```